# update to ubuntu 20.10 404?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

every time i try to do an update because I can«t find a certain package, i just get a bunch of 404s and error messages saying that my repositories no longer have a release file. this is really destroying my use of the system :/

meanwhile i discovered that i was running 22.04 (which claims to be LTS but repositories are dead?), and there's a 22.10 which has running repositories. so I tried to upgrade it!

well. this happened. same errors i get whenever I try to apt update.

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease         
Hit:6 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Err:8 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]
Ign:9 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                     
Err:10 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                    
Ign:13 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Err:14 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]
Hit:15 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Ign:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Hit:17 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Hit:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Ign:19 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease           
Ign:20 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease         
Err:21 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:23 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Ign:24 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 InRelease
Err:25 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Hit:26 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release
Hit:28 http://archive.ubuntu.csg.uzh.ch/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sido apt-get upgrade
Command 'sido' not found, did you mean:
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo (1.9.9-1ubuntu2)
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo-ldap (1.9.9-1ubuntu2)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
raiton@ubuntu:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
raiton@ubuntu:~$ nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
raiton@ubuntu:~$ 
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
raiton@ubuntu:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

= Welcome to Ubuntu 22.10 'Kinetic Kudu' =

The Ubuntu team is proud to announce Ubuntu 22.10 'Kinetic Kudu'.

To see what's new in this release, visit:
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KineticKudu/ReleaseNotes

Ubuntu is a Linux distribution for your desktop or server, with a fast
and easy install, regular releases, a tight selection of excellent
applications installed by default, and almost any other software you
can imagine available through the network.

We hope you enjoy Ubuntu.

== Feedback and Helping ==

If you would like to help shape Ubuntu, take a look at the list of
ways you can participate at

  http://www.ubuntu.com/community/participate/

Your comments, bug reports, patches and suggestions will help ensure
that our next release is the best release of Ubuntu ever.  If you feel
that you have found a bug please read:

  http://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Then report bugs using apport in Ubuntu.  For example:

  ubuntu-bug linux

will open a bug report in Launchpad regarding the linux package.

If you have a question, or if you think you may have found a bug but
aren't sure, first try asking on the #ubuntu or #ubuntu-bugs IRC
channels on Libera.Chat, on the Ubuntu Users mailing list, or on the
Ubuntu forums:

  http://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat
  http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-users
  http://www.ubuntuforums.org/


== More Information ==

You can find out more about Ubuntu on our website, IRC channel and wiki.
If you're new to Ubuntu, please visit:

  http://www.ubuntu.com/


To sign up for future Ubuntu announcements, please subscribe to Ubuntu's
very low volume announcement list at:

  http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce


Continue [yN] y   
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1270 kB]                                                   
Fetched 1271 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
authenticate 'kinetic.tar.gz' against 'kinetic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'kinetic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish InRelease
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy InRelease                               
Hit https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                    
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                   
Hit https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                       
Hit https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                          
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                  
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease           
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Ign https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]                                       
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]                                       
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]                                       
Hit https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease      
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                       
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]                                      
Ign https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 InRelease                        
Hit https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release                          
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Get:1 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic InRelease [267 kB]                  
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                   
Hit https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                          
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease           
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                       
Ign https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]                                      
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Get:2 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse i386 Packages [118 kB]   
Get:3 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 Packages [236 kB]  
Get:4 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse Translation-en [112 kB]  
Hit https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Get:5 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [39,8 kB]
Get:6 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [46,7 kB]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [179 kB]
Get:8 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [904 B]
Get:9 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8408 B]
Get:10 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 Packages [120 kB] 
Get:11 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 Packages [31,1 kB] 
Get:12 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/restricted Translation-en [18,0 kB]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [488 B]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe i386 Packages [7943 kB]   
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease [267 kB]          
Get:16 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 Packages [14,5 MB]  
Get:17 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe Translation-en [5791 kB]  
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease [90,7 kB] 
Get:19 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3718 kB]
Get:20 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3466 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease [90,7 kB]
Get:22 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7703 kB]
Get:23 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [74,4 kB]
Get:24 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [291 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main i386 Packages [1040 kB]       
Get:26 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages [1384 kB]      
Get:27 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main Translation-en [509 kB]       
Get:28 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [428 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages [1384 kB]
Get:30 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [97,3 kB]  
Get:31 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [144 kB]   
Get:32 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15,8 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main i386 Packages [1040 kB]
Get:34 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30,2 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main Translation-en [509 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [428 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [97,3 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [144 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15,8 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30,2 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 Packages [31,1 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 Packages [120 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted Translation-en [18,0 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [488 B]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe i386 Packages [7943 kB]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 Packages [14,5 MB]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe Translation-en [5791 kB]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3718 kB]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3466 kB]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7703 kB]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [74,4 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [291 kB]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse i386 Packages [118 kB]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 Packages [236 kB]
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse Translation-en [112 kB]
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [39,8 kB]
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [46,7 kB]
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [179 kB]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [904 B]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8408 B]
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main i386 Packages [5088 B]
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 Packages [36,2 kB]
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main Translation-en [10,6 kB]
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [55,4 kB]
Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/restricted Translation-en [9760 B]
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:72 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:73 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 96,9 MB in 6s (15,9 MB/s)                                              
Hit http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                             
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                   
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease           
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Hit https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                          
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                       
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]                                      
Ign https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                      
Hit https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease             
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Hit http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                             
Hit https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                          
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                   
Ign http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease           
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]                                      
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                       
Ign https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Err http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                      
Hit https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease             
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for 
repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 
'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not 
have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done 
securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) 
manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu 
impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file., W:Updating 
from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository 
creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 
'http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a 
Release file. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
```

any fix for this?

Edit1:
output for purposed solution:

```
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sudo cp -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.backup
[sudo] password for raiton: 
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
raiton@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:5 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:6 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]
Err:7 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.115.110.212 80]
Ign:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Ign:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease            
Ign:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Err:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Err:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Ign:14 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Err:15 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.136.212.166 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012) impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Edit4:
cant post all but
found stuff in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list-backup
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade
```

and a folder called

```
/etc/apt/sources.backup/
```

with tons of stuff like

```
/etc/apt/sources.backup/scootersoftware.list:............
/etc/apt/sources.backup/maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-impish.list.save:............
```

Comment: The title says "update to 20.10", but  you're already at 22.04?

Comment: @RayButterworth  . yes update from .04 to .10 ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have several additional repositories installed that have the distro version hard-coded in them that has since been removed (EOL).

To confirm your current Ubuntu version you can run `lsb_release -a`, I would remove all the custom APT repos first, do an update then retry.

```
sudo cp -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources-backup
sudo cp -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list-backup
```

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Replace the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` with:

```
deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

The update and do your upgrade :

```
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy


I have neofetch though which outputs the version as well :)

Comment: edited with problem to your solution

Comment: .. in which case there will be legacy repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can confirm this by doing `grep -r "old-releases.ubuntu.com" /etc/apt`.

If this is the case i would replace `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the [default](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ukj7og/complete_sourceslist_file_for_ubuntu_2204_lts/).

Comment: there's a few lines with that grep. i'm going to replace the sources.list and let you know :)

Comment: edit3. didn't work either

Comment: It might be stuck in cache, try clearing it `sudo apt-get clean all`… if memory serves. To my knowledge there is no other places that apt stores repo data but you could do the grep on /etc `grep -r deb /etc` and see if there are any other non-standard locations and remove those… taking a backup first of course :P

Comment: cleaned, same issue.. can't download any software...
edited with grep found sources.
a few are in a backup created in a tutorial, the distpugrade no idea